Which design is better
I am newbie in web, só I need your help.
Consider the two approaches below:
1-There is a smart contract MyFactory responsible for creating instances of MyImpl. Each instance has the same behavior, only differing in constructor data. Users can directly call functions on MyImpl, for example, myFunc().
2-There is a smart contract MyManager responsible for creating instances of MyImpl. Each instance has the same behavior, only differing in constructor data. Users interact with MyImpl instances through MyManager, e.g., MyManager.myFunc() calls SomeMyImpl.myFunc().
Which approach is better, and what are the pros and cons of each?
Can a smart contract be "busy" I mean in case of huge demand?
Thank you.

the second approach spends 9000 gas more, than the first, because of external CALL instruction. But if you want to keep the control of what the user does, you should go for the second approach. Maybe you should check for OpenZeppelin upgradable proxy patterns if you are building this kind of application

If there's no need to go through the manager, then don't force users to go through the manager.
Going straight to the implementation has a few benefits:

The sender of the call (msg.sender) is the user and not the manager
Saves some gas
It's explicit with which contract users are interacting with (though this may also be a bad thing)

However, in some cases, going through the manager may be desired. For example:

The manager tracks some common state
Users (or, the user interfaces they use) don't need to know which implementation they're interacting with, since the manager decides that

So it all depends on the use case.
A smart contract can't be "busy" in the sense you describe. If there are a lot of transactions targeting a smart contract, it just means the blockchain may get busy and gas prices may go up.

I really appreciate you help. Thank you, I will consider It.
